# AJAX request to get results from Google

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to modify the code in [this AJAX example](http://w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_httpsuggest) to get results from Google.

I take it out the line with the Random() method call, but how do I work with the query string in the JavaScript? How can I best do this using `XMLHttpRequest` to manually build the request (this is for testing so has to be manually done, as opposed to using a framework).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` with an absolute URL like `http://www.google.com/...`.

The browser will prevent [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You have to use a relative path, otherwise most browsers will simply return an empty `responseText`.

As one possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are on Apache). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) is the ProxyPass. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass     /ajax/     http://www.google.com/search
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `/ajax/?hl=en&source=hp&q=test` but in fact the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=test`.

If you are using IIS, you may want to use the [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=urlrewriter) to set up a reverse proxy.

Comment: So a relative url which is on the same server only? Can I use local files on my desktop (Eg to read from)?

Comment: Basically Yes. The files have to be accessed with a relative URL, like that in the w3schools example you provided. However check out my updated answer for a possible workaround by using a reverse proxy.

Comment: Good answer. Just one thing: So if I run a page on my browser locally, I can still work with a file which may be in the same folder? While local only. I tried this today but got 0 (basically nothing read in a populated .txt file).

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you do not use a file path like: `"file:///C:/path_to/file.txt"`. Simply use `"file.txt"` in `XMLHttpRequest.open()`.

Comment: Ah, tried it while I was not on this thread, is working now. Must be some oversight on my work machine.